# CDC engine in IBM, I cannot start TCP listener job

Tags: ibm-midrange, cdc, ibm-data-replication

I set up CDC engine for `DB2 for i` for my client. I installed it okay. Started DMIRROR subsystem okay but when I start TCP listener job (STRDMTCP), this job cannot start. In the job log, it shows this error:

```
 Message.....Failure on QUSPTRUS call.

 Message.....Operation not valid on system domain object.
 Cause..... The requested operation is not valid on a system domain object. The object name is DMCREG in library *CURLIB.
 Recovery.....You should use application programming interfaces to access system domain objects. An alternative is to create the object into the user domain. The QALWUSRDMN system value controls which libraries may contain user domain.objects.

Message.....Failure to obtain a key value for key CMN_JOBD.Failure code = 2. Please contact technical support for assistance.
 
Message..... Failure to initialize TCP Listener.TCP Listener encountered an error during initialization and can not continue execution. Please see previous message for more information about the error.

CDC Engine v.11.4.0
OS IBM i V7R3
Installer account : QSECOFR
```

Any ideas on how to fix this problem? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution to solve this problem. In my customer server, they `set QALWUSRDMN` system value with a specific library. I change it to `*ALL and re-install CDC engine again.` Now, it can start normaly.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to run the following command:
CHGCURLIB    then  TSSETREG, now set the product library and CDC subsystem, and try starting CDC subsystem and TCP listener.

Also, please check user account access requirements for "CDC Replication Engine for Db2 for i" section in below link:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSTRGZ_11.4.0/com.ibm.cdcdoc.sysreq.doc/concepts/useraccountaccessrequirements.html

Authority requirements fro CDC Replication Engine for Db2® for i users:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSTRGZ_11.4.0/com.ibm.cdcdoc.cdcfori.doc/concepts/authorityrequirements.html

Thanks
Sudarshan K

Comment: I use QSECOFR account to operate CDC engine command, I think QSECOFR has all of the authority that CDC required. I change current lib to DMIRROR before run STRDMTCP already. Do you have any idea?